# How do I find the oldest date for a customer on excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of dates in column `A` and customer numbers in column `B`.

There are multiple dates for each customer (representing invoice dates).  I need to find the oldest date for each customer.

Comment: (1) what have you tried to do so far to achieve this? (2) When there are multiple dates for one customer, are they in different rows or in the same cells separated by commas?

Comment: "How do I find the oldest date for a customer on excel?"  Have Excel search for the customer's escort at a retirement home?  Sorry.  I tried not to do that but just couldn't resist.

Comment: Just use a Pivot Table, (Customer to Rows, Date to Values), and, in Value Settings, show the Minimum value

Answer (score 6):

With data as you describe, in column`C` enter the list of customer numbers.  In cell `D1` enter the *Array Formula*:

```
=MIN(IF(B$1:B$24=C1,A$1:A$24,""))
```

and then, copy down *(this is because the oldest date will have the smallest value)*:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Column `D` should be given a *Date* number-format.